# Can't add trusted node to the first node

Tags: substrate-node-template

I deployed subtrate-node-template on 2 AWS instances after testing successfully on my local machine. I'm trying to add a trusted node to the bootnode, fork from substrate-node-template, but I meet this error:

```
Bootnode with peer id `12D3xxxxxxxx` is on a different chain (our genesis: 0xe5e2…0852 theirs: 0x411d…6454)
```

I use **scp** to save that file - customSpecRaw.json - to my machine and upload to the second node. In addition, I check md5sum 2 files with the same hash result.

Please help me.

Comment: What CLI commands did you use to run templates?

Comment: I'm using command as guideline:
```./target/release/node-template \
  --base-path /tmp/node02 \
  --chain ./customSpecRaw.json \
  --port 30333 \
  --ws-port 9945 \
  --rpc-port 9933 \
  --telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
  --validator \
  --rpc-methods Unsafe \
  --name MyNode02 \
  --bootnodes /ip4/<ip.from.above.step>/tcp/30333/p2p/id_from_above_step \
  --password-interactive
```